# Visually distinguish achievements & inbox items from Documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation, notifications, global-inbox

It would be nice to visually distinguish inbox notifications and achievements items from Documentation, currently, they look the same as ones from Q&A; and it's thus impossible to visually tell where they come from:

[image]

I think it would be nice to do what was done during the private beta, namely to use a different icon for things coming from Documentation:

[image]

With a different icon, it was easy to distinguish what came from Documentation and what came from Q&A, which I think was very useful. Can we have something like this back, in some form?

Comment: Freehand arrows at their best... Good work!

Comment: I seem to remember seeing two Docs icons next to each other on the left (one was the site icon, the other was Docs).

Comment: Seems like Privilege(most likely there are others as well) notifications from docs have both icons. http://i.stack.imgur.com/He1Nd.png

Comment: While Documentation is conceptually separate from QA, the reputation gain goes into the same pot. However, I agree that from a user feedback perspective, it would indeed be better to have a distinction between the two.

Comment: The items are site scope. Basically you want the identifiers to change from site to sub-functionality? Imagine documentation for i.e. Server Fault

Comment: @Aphelon - an possibility might be to show both icons - see [the screenshot linked to in Lafexlos's comment](http://i.stack.imgur.com/He1Nd.png).